# Docker nginx image issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx

I’m newbie in using docker, but I want to dockerize my node.js + nginx + react.js app via docker compose and I get this error when trying create nginx image (login via docker hub doesn’t help):

```
ERROR [nodereactcrm_client] FROM docker.io/library/build:latest
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to load cache key: pull access denied, repository
does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

My react Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine as builder


WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . ./

FROM nginx

COPY --from=build /home/node/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./server
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./server:/app
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    depends_on:
      - db
  client:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./client
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client:/app
    links:
      - api
    ports:
      - '80:80'
```

Comment: There's a typo. You named the first step as `builder` but you try to `COPY --from=build`. There is no such image and so does it say you in the  error.

Comment: @anemyte thank you! It works, but I faced another issue: COPY --from=builder /home/node/dist /usr/share/nginx/html:
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to compute cache key: "/home/node/dist" not found: not found. I really have no idea which path should I write to this step

Comment: Then get into the container and find out. Build the image `docker build --target builder --tag tmp .` then open a shell in it `docker run --rm -it tmp ash`. Use command line tools to inspect files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @anemyte answered - there was a typo. I needed just change `COPY --from=build` to `COPY --from=builder`